# Springwebflow and primefaces on liferay portlet issue

Tags: primefaces, liferay, spring-webflow

Hi I need to interate springwebflow with primefaces in the portlet environment.But I am facing many issues in implementation.Can someone pls provide a sample portlet with springwebflow and primefaces or tell about this.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few references I could find for you

primefaces

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Primefaces+portlet+tutorial

spring webflow

http://web.princeton.edu/sites/isapps/jasig/2006summerVancouver/Presentations/WebFlow-nojars.pdf

http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/05/29/getting-started-with-portals-writing-a-portlet-with-spring-portlet-mvc-and-deploying-it-to-a-portal/

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was posted at the [Liferay forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/30890164). Recommendation is to use JSF 2.2 Faces Flows instead of Spring Web Flow.